# Problems fixing java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version 52

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, unsupported-class-version

I've read all of the posts about this that I could find, but I can't seem to get past this error to get my maven spring mvc web application working. I just get an HTTP status 500 when i visit localhost or any of the URIs specified in my controllers.

From my understanding, the problem occurs because of a higher JDK used at compile time than used at runtime.  But it seems to me like all of the references to a JDK or JRE are the same in my case. (1.8) According to this stack overflow post it would appear that I need to be using java 1.8, so I'm not sure what the problem is:

[How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

**Steps I've Taken**

I made sure my pom.xml file references java 1.8. In intellij: under Compiler settings I set the target bytecode version is 1.8. Under Maven settings the JDK for importer is set to java 1.8, as is the runner. In project structure the project SDK is set to java 1.8 and the project language level is set to 8. I've also checked java.com and confirmed that version of java running in internet explorer is the same version 1.8 as my JDK and JRE. I have also made sure that my PATH variable on my computer is pointing to the correct JDK. As a shot in the dark, I also tried changing all of the references to use java 1.7, but still got the same error after deploying.

Below I've listed my pom.xml file and the stack trace for the error. As always, thanks for the time and assistance!

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.projectName.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Test Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.5.49</mysql.connector.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.5.50</mysql.connector.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- JDBC Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HSQL Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson To Convert java to JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Application View -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**stack trace**

```
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet springDispatcherServlet threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet springDispatcherServlet threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)


root cause 

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: springmvc/controllers/AccountController : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class springmvc.controllers.AccountController)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2506)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:831)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:247)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1346)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1317)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1394)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:385)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:362)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:348)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051)
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:119)
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:103)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:126)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: This error simply means: You are running a JVM version 7 or lower and try to load classes compiled with Java 8.

Comment: When I run java -version on the command line it shows that I'm running Java 8.

Comment: And you also do start your tomcat on the comand line with "java ..."?

Comment: Better remove all other Java versions except for version 8. This is no mystery, it's **always** the same reason.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose No I just navigate to the path of the tomcat directory and execute the startup.bat. Should I be starting it a different way?

Comment: I asked that question, because starting tomcat and running java on the comman line obviously start two different versions on your machine. You have to analyse why and where.

Comment: @Kayaman That did the trick. Turns out my JRE_HOME variable was referencing the java 1.7 jre when I started up Tomcat. Once I deleted 1.7 it wouldn't let me start up tomcat without changing my JRE_HOME. Appreciate the help from both of you!

Comment: @Kayaman if you want you can just repeat what you said as an answer and i'll mark it as the one that solved the problem.

Comment: @user3792733 That should explain things nicely.

Comment: That it did, thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UnsupportedClassVersionError` is **always** due to the fact that a class was compiled with a Java version greater than the Java version being used to run it.

When you have an `IDE`, an app server like `Tomcat` and other things, you may have several settings that must point to a `JDK` (with the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable being the most important). If they all point to the correct place, there's no problem, however there are possibilities for errors such as:

- Setting points to `JRE` instead of `JDK`

This causes problems when there's a need for `javac` which doesn't exist in the `JRE`. For example `Tomcat` needs `javac` to compile things, so `JRE` is not enough.

- Setting points to a different `JDK` than other settings

This causes the `UnsupportedClassVersionError`, and then you need to find which setting is wrong. Often `JAVA_HOME` points to the correct place, but a different setting points to an older `JDK`. A common problem is having `JAVA_HOME` point to Oracle's JDK and Tomcat pointing to `OpenJDK`.

Since you can use `-source` and `-target` flags to compile for older versions, you don't need to keep more than one JDK on your system. Remove the old ones and the chances for mysterious errors diminish.